# Перестал работать share в facebook так, как работал раньше. Что использовать?

Tags: facebook, share, ya-share2

Для вконтакте рамотает все великолепно, можно передавать заголовок, описание и картинки без каких бы то ни было проблем. Facebook работал точно также буквально пару месяцев назад, теперь же, используя код

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="window.open('https://share.yandex.net/go.xml?service=facebook&url=&title=&description=&image=','fb','width=190,height=280,resizable=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')" class="content-test__soc__item content-test__soc__item--fb">Поделиться</a>
```

сервер facebook возвращает 404, в чем может быть проблема? и как исправить?

Микроразметку использовать не могу, так как url страницы один и тот же, а шерить необходимо три разных варианта.

Answer (score 2):

Адрес `https://share.yandex.net/go.xml` использовался в первой версии блока "Поделиться", сейчас не поддерживаемой.

Социальные сети периодически меняют свои API для поделения, поэтому нередко ссылки, которые прекрасно функционировали ранее, перестают работать.

В вашем случае можно либо напрямую использовать [API Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect), либо обновиться до [актуальной версии](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/) блока "Поделиться".

Comment: Но в любом случае необходимо будет использовать микроразметку? Или все-таки есть возможность отдавать кастомно?

Comment: В случае с facebook – только микроразметка.